# Set listener for store events in a controller

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, extjs, extjs4

I have a controller with a store, a model, and some views.

I need to listen for the `beforesync` and `write` event of the store in the controller, but I don't know how to set these listeners in the controllers `control`-function.

My store looks like this :

```
Ext.define('DT.store.UsersStore', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Store',
    model : 'DT.model.User',
    id : 'myStore'
    autoSync : true,
    proxy : {
        type : 'ajax',
        api : {
            read : '/load_entries',
            update : '/update_entry'
        },
        reader : {
            type : 'json',
            root : 'user',
            successProperty : 'success'
        }
    }
});
```

Now I try to listen to the events in my controller :

```
...
init : function () {
    this.control({
        'myStore' : {
            beforesync : this.doSomething,
            write : this.doSomethingElse
        }
    });
},
...
```

My expected result is that the functions will be executed, when the events are fired.
But at this time nothing happens when they are fired.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[Your way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193392/extjs4-set-listener-for-store-events-in-a-controller/7202455#7202455) is possible but it's not ideal, IMO. The better way is to use controllers's store getter. In your case the code would be something like this:

```
init : function () {
    // every controller has getters for its stores.
    // For store UsersStore getter would be getUsersStoreStore()
    this.getUsersStoreStore().addListener('write',this.finishedLoading, this);
    this.control({
        // widgets event handlers
    });
},
```

Comment: Even better, than my solution. Thanks man. This community is awesome.

Comment: Would this solution work correctly by ONLY executing the code while on a part of the app which is using the controller you define this in? Or would the event hit this new listener from this point forward?

Comment: I think it will only work inside this controller, but I don't know it exactly, because I've never used muliple controllers in one App.

Comment: There does not seem to be any getters for stores in ST2.1 beta

Answer (score 19):

Here is an alternative syntax to [Molecular Man's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7223173/20774).

Instead of writing,

```
init : function () {
    this.getUsersStoreStore().addListener('write',this.finishedLoading, this);
    this.control({
        // widgets event handlers
    });
},
```

You can write

```
init : function () {
    this.getUsersStoreStore().on({
        write: this.finishedLoading,
        scope: this
    });
    this.control({
        // widgets event handlers
    });
},
```

I think this alternative definition reads a little bit better.

I took this from an [answer Izhaki](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11870168/20774) gave me.

Comment: Can we add more than 1 listener using on() ?

Comment: out of all the solutions on this page only `this.getUsersStoreStore().on({..` worked for me. (Using 4.2.1)

Answer (score 5):

As for Extjs 4.2.1, your initial way of accessing the store listener would actually work, if you were using the 'storeId' instead of the id and the 'listen' function instead of 'control':

```
Ext.define('DT.store.UsersStore', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Store',
    model : 'DT.model.User',
    storeId : 'myStore'
    ....

init : function () {
    this.listen({
        store: {
           '#myStore' : {
               beforesync : this.doSomething,
               ...
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Ext.define('Store', {
    model: 'Model',
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    listeners: {
        'beforesync': function(){
            App.getController('somecontroller').onBeforeSync();
        }
    }
});
```

App - your application object
The function onBeforeSync you can implement it in the controller ... this is the only way i could assign the event to the store and still implement the logic in the controll. I hope it helps

Comment: No, this does not work. this.doSomething should execute a console.log('BeforeSync'); but still nothing happens

Comment: well the problem is clearly that the listener it's not assigned to the component. You should read the documentation for query in extjs, which is used to determine for what component tu assign the event. Try something like 'widgetname gridPanel #store' (where widgetname is for the view assigned to the controller). I don't have something to test at the moment but you should take it step by step, first add an event on the component containing that store and after that try to set events on the store.

Comment: D'oh... I found out that the store class has neither an id nor an alias config. My configs will be ignored and the item will not be assigned in the controller. Is there an other way?

Comment: I searched for alternatives and i couldn't find any. The control function uses component query to get the components, and store it's not an ext component, it extends ext.base, therefore i believe it's not possible to get a store using a component query. I found somehow an alternative, i'll modify the answer above with the solution i found

Comment: Please do not couple your store to the controller, this is a realy bad idea, you can't reuse this store in another part of your application.

Answer (score 4):

I solved it by myself.

I added the listener manually in the `render`-event of my Panel

```
Ext.getCmp('userPanel').down('gridpanel').getStore().addListener('write',this.finishedLoading, this);
```

Thank you for the help @nscrob.

Answer (score 1):

### Hope this addition will help someone out there to avoid spending some hours on debugging the library core:

Related to this practice of accessing Ext.data.Store instance inside Controller using the controller's getter method: e.g. for the "DT.store.UsersStore" above using this.getUsersStoreStore():

pay attention that if the store  is already associated in a view(e.g. was declared as the store property for a "UsersGrid" Grid.panel.Panel widget definition) then this **getter method will retrieve in fact another instance of the same Store class and not the instance used by the widget!** 
  The reason is that adding the store in the constructor configuration object like this:

```
stores: ['UsersStore']
```

will in fact add a new store instance in Ext.data.StoreManager.map hash so - supposing that 'UsersStore' is the only Store object instantiated so far  - the map keys now look like:

```
0: "ext-empty-store"
1: "UsersStore"
2: "myStore"
```

Now imagine you want to read some new data using your store'proxy and display this new data in the "UsersGrid" and you want to do all these when user clicks on something, so inside controller you will have a handler method for the user event with the code:

```
'user-selector' : {
    click: function(){
                     var oStoreReference = this.getUsersStoreStore();
                         oStoreReference.load( {params:{} });
            }
    }
```

That call to get the reference will be translated internally in this.getStore('UsersStore') and will return a reference to the controller generated - 1: "UsersStore" - and not - 2: "myStore" - as one might expected. Furthermore, the load() call will load the UsersStore instance with the new Models and this will not be reflected in your grid view(because the grid is bound and listens to the events generated by "myStore" store instance).

So better access the store by its itemId using the general getStore method: this.getStore('storeItemId')

Answer (score 0):

Why not just relay the store's events? For example:

`this.getUsersGrid().relayEvents(this.getUsersStoreStore(), ['write'], 'store')`

And then be able to

`this.control('somegrid-selector': {storeWrite: function(){...}})`

Answer (score 0):

Just in case somebody stumbels over this.

ExtJS 7.3

```
Ext.define('DT.controller.UsersStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    listen: {
        store: {
            UsersStore: {
                beforesync : 'doSomething',
                write : 'doSomethingElse'
            }
        }
    },

    doSomething() {
        console.log(arguments)
    },

    doSomethingElse() {
        console.log(arguments)
    }
});
```