# In ExtJs, how do I get an id after syncing a record to the store?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, store

**If I have a store under ExtJs 4, how do I get an id from a newly added record after a sync occurs?**

For example, if I have a `PersonStore` set to autosync and I add a new person based on a form filled out by the users, I can add the new record to the store by doing the following;

```
var values = button.up('form').getForm().getValues(),
    store = Ext.StoreMgr.lookup('PersonStore'),
    result;

result = store.add(values);
```

Since autosync is set to true, this sends over the new value to the backend where it is assigned an id. The backend then responds to the client with the id of the newly created record.

**How do I get the id for this newly created record in my client side code?** I had assumed that result would contain it, but result still has id set to null.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When the server side is the one setting the id, the workflow is this:

- Record added to the store without an id being assigned.
- Store syncs, so a Create request is being sent to the server.
- Server returns the sent record, with an id property set.
- ExtJS looks at the returned record and if it has an id set, it assignes it to the record.

Notice, by the way, that for all CRUD operations, the store record will be updated with the data returned from the server so long the id matches. In the case of newly created records, ExtJS has an internalId mechanism to determine that the record returned is the one sent, but with its id set.

The server side code might look something like this:

```
function Create( $aRecord )
{
    global $pdo;

    $iInsertClause = InsertClause::FromFields( self::$persistents );

    $iStatement = $pdo->prepare( "INSERT INTO Tags $iInsertClause" );
    $iStatement->execute( InsertClause::ObjectToParams( $aRecord, self::$persistents ) );

    // Inject the id into the record and return it in the reader's root,
    // so client side record updates with the new id.
    $aRecord->id = $pdo->lastInsertId();
    return array(
        'success' => true,
        'data'    => $aRecord,
    );
}
```

Then within your app, your controller should hook on store write events. Something like this:

```
init: function() {

    this.getTasksStore().on({
        write:  this.onStoreWrite,
        scope:  this            
    });
},
```

And within that function you can inspect the returned record (I assume `data` is the reader's root):

```
onStoreWrite: function ( aStore, aOperation )
{
        var iRecord = aOperation.response.result.data;
        console.log(iRecord.id);

},
```

Comment: Hello again :) I think I was unclear in my question, so I've updated it to clarify. The server is correctly returning the newly create id, but how do, on the client side, retrieve that newly created id?

Comment: That's happens automatically, given a few things are satisfied. Could you perhaps provide the request sent to the server and the server response. I take it you haven't played with idProperty, and that the id field is `id`.

Comment: Hold on a second. Did you means something like aRecord.get("id")? You can listen to store write events and inspect `aOperation.response.result`

Comment: Yeah, that looks like what I was looking for. Could you expand upon that in your answer? That object looks like it has what I need. Not sure how it get that to my controller. (Actually I might have spoken too soon, I see the id in the response text, I suppose I could parse JSON out of there, but I am probably just missing a more convenient method)

Comment: Found an answer for getting the listener in my controller, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193392

Comment: I've updated my answer to suggest how this may be done. This is a patch work of a working code, so might not be a copy-paste solution. But should give you a strong idea how to go about this.

Comment: Thanks, `aOperation.response.result.data` doesn't work for me, I ended    up using `aOperation.getRecords()[0].data`. This is under 4.0.7.

Comment: That's with a treestore maybe?

Comment: Nope, I am using an Ext.data.Store, http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store.